# How is the Arel#extract method used in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I am trying to use the Arel#extract method. I have seen an example in a test case in test_extract.rb in the source but when I try to reproduce it in my app, I get undefined method.

```
table = Arel::Table.new :users
puts table[:created_at].extract('hour').to_sql
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `extract' for #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute:0x7..8>
```

I am using pg as the database.

**Update:**

My goal is to end up with this result in sql:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR from users."created_at") = '1'
```

I would like to find all users that were created on the hour equal to one of any day. This works in sql but I am wondering how to create it in arel. Here is an [example](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/test/nodes/test_extract.rb#L6) of how it's used in the arel test suite.

Comment: I do not see `#extract` as part of the Arel::Table class in the docs. What are you trying to do? Retrieve `'date'` from the table?

Comment: I updated the description to answer your question.

Comment: Would an ActiveRecord query work better for you? `Users.where("Minute(?) = 1", :created_at).all`?

Comment: [Sorry, forgot you were on PG] Would an ActiveRecord query work better for you? `Users.where("EXTRACT(hour from ?) = 1", :created_at).all`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that but thanks anyway. The problem wasn't in Arel. It was only when used in Rails. I will post my finding when I better understand the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeYacoub any finding?

Comment: @delba sorry I couldn't do this using Arel.

Answer (score 2):

extract is node's method, you can cast it on any column(such as users[:id]), but not on Arel::Table instance.

So, to construct your query you need:

- get Arel::Table instance `users = Arel::Table.new(:users)` or if you use ActiveRecord - `users = User.arel_table`
- set SELECT statement on Arel::Table instance with `project` method: `users = users.project(Arel.sql('*'))`
- set WHERE statement with `where` method: `users.where(users[:created_at].extract(:hour).eq(1))`

In one block:

```
query = User.arel_table.
             project(Arel.sql('*')).
             where(users[:created_at].extract(:hour).eq(1))
users = User.find_by_sql(query)
# => "SELECT * FROM \"users\"  WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM \"users\".\"created_at\") = 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to perform an extract DOW on an instance of Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction, which does not expose the method #extract (as of Arel 6.0). I managed to achieve this by manually creating an instance of `Arel::Nodes::Extract`. Here is what worked for me, in case anyone have a similar issue:

`Arel::Nodes::Extract.new(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('some_function_name', [param1, param2, ...]),
  :dow
)`

You can use an Arel node directly with ActiveRecord's `#where` instead of building the full query through Arel as exemplified by Alexander Karmes's answer. So here is another way to perform the query required by the answer:

`User.where(
  Arel::Nodes::Extract.new(User.arel_table[:created_at], :hour).eq(1)
)`

Which yields:

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "users"."created_at") = 1`

With the added benefit you can keep chaining other scopes defined in your `User` model.